# how do I know I am dealing with the extra (empty) form within a formset?

Tags: django, django-forms

```
deals_formset_factory = modelformset_factory(Deal, form=DealForm, extra=1)   
formset = deals_formset_factory(queryset=query, prefix='deals')  


{% for fs in formset.forms %}
    {{ fs.id }}                     
{% endfor %}
```

While traversing through the forms of a formset, is it possible to find out which form contains instance data and which one is extra and hence empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to see whether the form instance has a primary key. If it does, then it exists in the database. If it doesn't, then it's an extra form.

Untested code:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% if form.instance.pk %}
    Form instance is saved in db
    {% else %}
    New instance
    {% endif %}                 
{% endfor %}
```